# Picture doesn't get the typical "Thumbnail" border with bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a wrote code to test bootstrap in general, but the used thumbnail class won't work. I've tested different variants (thumbnail used as class for the img and used as class for the div container) but they are not working either.

What exactly isn't working: The Picture doesn't get the typical "Thumbnail" border used to be with bootstrap.

I'm working in codepen actually and have double checked if the bootstrap is loaded.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="text-center">
          <h1>Alan Turing</h1>
          <h6>The man who hacked the code</h6>
          <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="http://scienceblogs.de/klausis-krypto-kolumne/files/2015/01/Turing-Bombe.png">
              <div class="caption">
                test
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What could possibly be the problem here? :(

Codepen Link: https://codepen.io/pr1mus/pen/VzWQzK/

Comment: I tested this outside of codepen and it works. So i suspect that it has something to do with the fact that it is on codepen..perhaps not including bootstrap correctly..Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `class="img-thumbnail"` to your `img` (as explained in [doc for v4 which you are using](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/images/#image-thumbnails)).

See [forked  CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MvoVgg).

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you include these. Also i didn't see that you included the JS. Make sure you include both the CSS and the JS. Check out the getting started page for some quick instructions: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: No need for the problem at hand, it's just CSS here -- Sorry I said "they", alright, but the CSS is there ;)